# Can someone explain how the recursion in this structure works?

Tags: recursion, linked-list

What is "next" here? Please explain how recursion works here? Thanks

`typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;`

Answer (score 0):

`next` is a pointer called `next` to a `struct node`.

The definition is recursive because you use a reference of what you define inside the definition.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type)

> recursive data type (also known as a recursively-defined, inductively-defined or inductive data type) is a data type for values that may contain other values of the same type.

It's like saying a `node_t` is a data type that consists in a `struct` that has two fields, one is an `int` called `val`, the other called `next` by the programmer is a pointer to a `node_t` (here is the recursive definition).